# Model relationship - ForeignKey or OneToMany?

Tags: python, django

I'm making a blog that has collection of my favorite videos for fun. Below are the models in my application:

```
# I want to categorize the videos
class blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) #name can be dogs, cats, cars
    relatedVideo = models.ForeignKey(video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class video(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) #the video name 
    description = models.TextField()
```

Have I connected these correctly?

Comment: If each blog has exactly one video, then this is indeed how you should model this. Since you first define `blog` however, you should use a string literal, so `models.ForeignKey('video', on_delete=...)`. It is however not very clear to me what the function of `blog` is here (since your `video` already has a `name` and `description` field).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem each blogs(sorry for misleading title, probably category will be a better name)) will have multipe related videos.

Comment: can every video have *one* category, or multiple ones?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes!! :) it's foreignkey right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think relation should be like this:

```
class blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) #name can be dogs, cats, cars

class video(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) #the video name 
    description = models.TextField()
    blog = models.ForeignKey(blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="related_videos")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

By this ForeignKey relation means, one blog can have multiple video. You can use this relation like this:

```
>>b = blog.objects.create(name="Some Name")
>>v1 = video.objects.create(blog=b, name="Video 1")
>>v2 = video.objects.create(blog=b, name="Video 2")
>>b.related_videos.all()
<QuerySet [<video: Video 1>, <video: Video 2>]>
```